# "best" chord name for a min♭6

Tags: guitar, chords, chord-theory

As I developed my (guitar) chord vocabulary, the [min7](http://home.comcast.net/~k2a/chords.html#min7) chords were followed by the [min6](http://home.comcast.net/~k2a/chords.html#min6) chords. One was different. In the major key, the iii is what I have called a [min♭6](http://home.comcast.net/~k2a/chords.html#minb6). However I have gotten some feedback that it shouldn't be named that. I realize that many chords have multiple names, and that the context is critical, but this is the name that I felt was most sensible in the context of the iii.

So, would you name a chord spelled G - B♭ - D - E♭ anything other than a [min♭6](http://home.comcast.net/~k2a/chords.html#minb6)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should name it Eb maj7 because that's what it actually is. If the lowest note is G, then it is just the first inversion of Eb maj7.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that m6 is G-Bb-D-E. It's a bit of a misnomer, but it is a minor triad with a major 6th note added. So I, bIII V VI. The addition of the proper m6 interval clashes with the V, but could be called mb6.It's more commonly found as Ebmaj7, though, and in the order shown would be the 1st inversion - not sounding as good as the root.Sometimes on guitar, it's difficult to keep a simple or tasteful voicing of a particular chord, and quite often the lowest note needs to be the root, unless others are playing too. This is best with Eb at the bottom.